# Copy one column from a database table to another column in another database table sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I had two databases (A and B), both were identical until I messed up one column in Table T1 on database A... basically set all records in that column to NULL. How do I update that incorrect column in T1 on database A with the correct data from its equivalent column from database B?

My insert command did not work as there are more columns in T1 on database A which do not allow null values to be inserted.

```
insert into A.dbo.finance (finishdate)
select finishdate 
from B.dbo.finance
```

I tired to do an inner join, but it says "multi-part identifier could not be bound". Unfortunately the data in the other tables in database A has since changed hence simply using database B is not an option :-)

Could someone please assist?

Comment: Why are you inserting if you wish to change the value of one column? Shouldn't it be an UPDATE?

Comment: very true Nadeem. The update command worked for me :-) Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If ID is the id column of both tables, you should join them and update the one you want:

```
UPDATE A.dbo.finance
SET    finishdate = B.finishdate 
FROM   A.dbo.finance A
       JOIN B.dbo.finance B
           ON A.ID = B.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

DATABASE B

```
Select finishdate into ##temp from dbo.finance B where 1 = 1
```

DataBase A

```
    insert into dbo.finance(finishdate)
    select * from ##temp t where NOT EXISTS
(Select 1 from dbo.finance WHERE finishdate <> t.finishdate  )
```